# Call a method once a ThreadPool thread completes its work

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have to run some piece of code as a separate thread on ThreadPool.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyMethod,MyObjects);
```

I need to run another method MyMethod2 once MyMethod is completed. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean to execute that function once the entire ThreadPool finishes the work?

Comment: add clarification to question

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => { MyMethod(o); MyOtherMethod(); }, MyObjects);
```

Comment: @Tudor, yes; unless I misunderstood, this is what the OP wants

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (TPL) instead:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //your method call(s) here
    })
    .ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
       //your on completion code here
    });
```